# Can I build Apple Watch app without iPhone companion app

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am planning to build an Apple watch app that should interact with an external device via Bluetooth. So, can I build just an apple watch app without iPhone Companion app?​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can starting with watchOS 6.

Comment: @user3584797 No problem. With WWDC coming in a month, maybe this will change soon?

Comment: hoping so Austin

Comment: @user3584797 It's announced you can for watchOS 6!

Comment: Yeah, Got to know about it from recent wwdc

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 it's possible to create independent watchOS application. More information can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps). You have to download Xcode 11 to be able to create independent watchOS application.

To create it simply go to File -> New -> Project and select watchOS -> App as it's shown on a screenshot:
[image]

There is also WWDC 2019 video: [Creating Independent Watch Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/208/).